# "create" event using jquery's "live"

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to run some code on new objects? Something like this:

```
$('.some_class').live('create', function() {
  $(this).append('something');
}
```

So `something` will be appended to all elements with class `some_class` (existing and future ones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Jquery Plugin called livequery which covers your requirements.

I like to think of this plugin as Jquery .live() but without the need for an event ('click') etc. (It actually listens for dom events)

You can find more info here//

[Jquery - Live Query Plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery)

Your example would be as follows

```
$('.some_class').livequery(function() {  $(this).append('something');});
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if you dont wish to use the livequery plugin...

You can use delegate events to new objects too using .delegate();

```
$("body").delegate(".newdiv", "click", function(){alert('new div clicked')});
```

Or you can bind something to a AJAX success using .ajaxSuccess()

```
$('.someclass').ajaxSuccess(function() {
 $(this).append('something');
});
```

Comment: is it different from doing `$("body .newdiv").live("click", function(){alert('new div clicked')});` ?

Comment: only in the fact you can specify a element in the root of another with delegate.

Jquery documentation can explain these better

Comment: Interesting, I'll check that out. Thanks!

Comment: Delegate is actually more efficient too. 
Chris Coyier writes about it here.
http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/

Comment: No idea, works perfectly well and is actually more efficient than the accepted answer. Feel free to up-vote :)

Comment: how would you do this without specifying on click? Or is that when you need to use the plugin of which the link doesn't work anymore :( I tried removing the click part but no dice...

Comment: in thgis scenario you would need to listen to any other event or if no events exist use the plugin . https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery